# Can T-Net be substituted by data augmentation in the PointNet architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I am looking at the [PointNet](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1612.00593) architecture at I was wondering why T-Net was preferred over data augmentation.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think of T-Net as trying to find a transformation that will make the classification easier for the network (just like it is easier for us to classify an upside down image by rotating it).

Couldn't we replace the T-Net with data augmentation? I.e. perform rotations, flips etc?

Moreover, T-Net is subsequently used as a feature transform, but I can't understand what is the point of applying it again in this step.